# Insert date into SQL database from Angular form

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a form in my HTML file that allows the user to choose a date, this input binds to an Angular value. The value is then sent into a PHP file to be inserted into a database. Below is the code that shows how i currently have it set up.

HTML input form

```
<input class="input" ng-model="release" type="date" />
```

Angular controller

```
$http.post("php/addEpisode.php", {
        'release': $scope.release})
```

PHP file

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
@$release = $request->release;

$query = "INSERT INTO episode ( release ) 
          VALUES ( '{$release}' )";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

All the other values (which are not shown here) that are inserted into the table work fine. It is just this value that is an issue.

In the database the 'release' value is stored as a date with a format of 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

<---EDIT--->

I have found the reason it was not working. The name of the column in the table could not be set to 'release', it had to be something different as 'release' is a key word.

Comment: Debugging, when you have no ideas to investigate, becomes a methodical process of converting *assumptions* into *confirmed facts* until you find your faulty assumption or have gathered enough info to generate some ideas/hypotheses.  Usually it's good to start with an assumption "in the middle" to see which "side" the problem is on.  In your PHP, could you print out the value of $postdata to confirm what's really really in it (and not what we assume is in it)?

Comment: When i print out the value of $postdata it contains what i expect. I have even printed the value of $query to see if the actual query is what i expect, which it is, so i dont understand why the query is not executing properly.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me very well

**in html**

```
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">*Fecha Radicacion</label>
            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <md-datepicker 
                        ng-model="formulario.fechaRadicacion" 
                        disabled
                        >
                    </md-datepicker>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**in the controller**

```
    $scope.fechaRadicacion = new Date();
    $scope.fechaActual=function(){
        $scope.formulario.fechaRadicacion=$scope.fechaRadicacion.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
        console.log("esta es la fecha en radicacion JS ",$scope.fechaRadicacion);
        console.log("esta es a fecha en formulario.fechaRadicacion",$scope.formulario.fechaRadicacion);
    }
```

**in the PHP**

`//echo 'el dato es :<pre>'.$r->formulario->fechaRadicacion.;`